# What does dd do when the destination drive runs out of space?

Tags: disk-space, dd, ddrescue

I tried to make a drive image using ddrescue, but I'm not sure if the destination drive had enough space.  Does dd just silently continue to try writing to the drive even when it has run out of space?  Did it just truncate the file and report no errors on the log file?  So when I try to restore from it data will be missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dd errors out with a not enough space on device message. Not sure what ddrescue does, but I'd assume it's similar.

Answer (score 1):

If dd did not error out with an `Not Enough Space` message, I would assume that the copy went off w/o an issue.

The old motto still applies tho.

Assume but verify.

If you have another hard drive laying around (or need another one... who doesn't need another one), i'd try to do the copy and see if everything was copied correctly...